# Using player selectors in titles in minecraft 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing Minecraft 1.13.2 and I am trying to code a command block that outputs a Title when a player dies. The Title needs to include the dead players name. This is the code I have but it just lists all players on line, not the one that died.

```
/execute if entity @a[scores={Deaths=1}] run title @a title [{"selector":"@a Deaths=1]"},{"text":" has died! "}]
```

Comment: You already have the right syntax in `execute`, why did you use something else in `title`? Just use the same.

Comment: Thanks Fabian but Im not sure what you mean. Are you able to give me an example?

Comment: No example needed, just copy what you wrote after `entity` into the selector field.

Comment: the `/title` command and signs use exactly the same JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

/execute as @a[scores={Deaths=1}] run title @a title {text":"","extra":[{"selector":"@a[scores={Deaths=1}]},{"text":" has died! "}]} Should do it.

Comment: Did you try it? The brackets aren't even balanced.

Comment: You're right, I'm missing a ].  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You also didn't close your double-quotes... this is still malformed JSON...